# *ngif inside ng-template not working - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have the following code. The problem is that when "currentUser$" changes its value, the button does not change state (visible / hidden) but if I change the tab, and I return, the button appears

```
// generic-table.component.ts

<div>
    ...
    ...
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="headerButtonsTemplateRef"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{isLoading: isLoading}">
    </ng-template>
    ...
    ...
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>

//change-user.component.ts

changeUser(){
    
    this.authenticationService._currentUserSubject.next(new User())

}

//entity-list.component.html

<generic-table [headerButtonsTemplateRef]="headerButtonTemplate"><generic-table>

<ng-template #headerButtonTemplate let-isLoading="isLoading">
    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" [disabled]="isLoading" (click)="createEntity()"
        *ngIf="this.authenticationService.currentUser$ | checkPermission:entityCreate | async">
    </button>
    <button>
        ANOTHER-BUTTON-ALWAYS-VISIBLE
    </button>
    <button>
        ANOTHER-BUTTON-ALWAYS-VISIBLE
    </button>
</ng-template>

//general-list.component.html

<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" animationDuration="0ms">
    <mat-tab label="TAB 1">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <entity-list></entity-list>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="TAB 2">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <other-component></other-component>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

//pipe

export class CheckPermissionPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private jwtService: JwtService) { }

    transform(value: any, claimDTO: IClaimDTO[]): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.jwtService.checkPermissionAsync(claimDTO)
    }
}
```

Comment: You've omitted the most important bit of code, the `checkPermission` pipe.

Comment: Oops. I already update the post. Thx

Comment: That pipe seems very strange. Shouldn't it be `transform(user$: Observable<User>, claims: IClaimDTO[]) { return user$.pipe(flatMap(user => this.jwtService.checkPermissionAsync(user, claims))); }` or something like that? It's hard to tell since adding the pipe definition, as requested, reveals much more that's missing

Comment: You are absolutely right, that is the problem, I thought the async pipes worked differently. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help.